# How to display date string in given timezone using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, dayjs

The time is given in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` format, for example `2023-04-30T16:00:00-05:00`.
And I want to display `2023-04-30 04:00 PM EST` using `dayjs`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely possible. The `-05:00` part just represents a timezone offset, but you want the name of a timezone in your output. `-05:00` can refer to multiple different timezone names, not just `EST`.

Comment: `dayjs('2023-01-11T16:50:00-05:00').tz('America/Toronto').format('h:mm a z')` prints `4:50 pm EST` so I think this should be possible.

Comment: I wish dayjs would provide `dayjs.tz.guess(string)`

Comment: I wrote an answer a while back that attempted to convert between offset and name [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512632/how-to-get-a-timezone-name-from-iso-string-in-javascript/75512963#75512963). I'm not well versed in day.js, but it seems that dayjs **is** able to convert between offset and name if you provide a locale-ish thing like `America/Toronto`.